# Adding a result from loop to a variable

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var brojevi: ArrayInt = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
        
    for(i in 1..10)
    brojevi.add([i])
        
    println(brojevi)    
}
```

how to add numbers from 1 to 10 in brojevi variable

Comment: if I wasnt trying I wouldnt be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays in Kotlin are fixed-size. That means once created, we can’t resize them. To get a resizable-array implementation, consider using MutableList instead, which can grow or shrink automatically as needed.

However, if you’re stuck on using arrays, you can create a new array to accommodate the additional element.

The trick is to convert the array into a MutableList, add the specified element at the end of the list, and finally return an array containing all the elements in this list.

Try this

```
fun main() {
    var brojevi: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
    var tempList: MutableList<Int> = brojevi.toMutableList()

    for(i in 1..10) {
        tempList.add(i)
    }

    var resultArray = tempList.toTypedArray()
    println(resultArray.contentToString())
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot you saved me! Have a nice day!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you may mark that answer as accepted answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Check here how to use for loops in Kotlin
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression